# How can I add a label on the right side in Vuetify Navigation Drawer

Tags: vuetify.js

I like to add a label on the right side in the menu like on the Vuetify doc page.

[image: label screenshot]

I tried with `v-label` but I was not able to put it on the right side.

I checked the code of the Vuetify page, but I didn't found the solution.

What is the right code to do this?

Comment: It's an x-small size chip https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chips/#sizes

Comment: @AneesHameed how can i put it on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a **label inside navigation drawer**

Just need to use v-chip component and use styling to move towards right.

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/wvKdReR?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      height="400"
      width="256"
      class="mx-auto"
    >
      <v-navigation-drawer permanent>
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title class="title">
              Application
            </v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>
              subtext
            </v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-list
          dense
          nav
        >
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            link
          >
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>

            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}
              <v-chip v-if="item.new" style="float: right;" color="primary" x-small>
                  new
                </v-chip>

              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard' },
        { title: 'Photos', icon: 'mdi-image' },
        { title: 'About', icon: 'mdi-help-box', new: true },
      ],
      right: null,
    }
  },
})
```